# Laravel 4: Eloquent Conflict

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am trying to do eloquent with this:

```
$product = new Product;
$product->name = $name;
$product->price = $price;
$product->save();
```

And I get this error:

```
Call to undefined method Product::save()
```

After some checking with `var_dump($product)`, I found that it is caused by the problem that Laravel doesn't load the Product class which is located in `Models` folder. But the problem is, I can't find what are the other product class that override it. From all the files I have created in Laravel, only one file in the `Models` folder call `Product.php` with the class name `Product` in it.

This is my Product.php file in models folder

```
class Product extends Eloquent{
    protected $table = 'myproduct';
}
```

I have tried rename the Product to Myproduct and it works. But I need to find out why Product doesn't works. Is the product class reserved by laravel? If not, can you please suggest what are the possible places that will cause laravel not loading the Product class from the Models folder?

Thank you.

Comment: It would be better if you provide some code. My guess: `Product` class does not extend `Eloquent`.

Comment: I have added my Product.php code into the question.

Comment: ... have you `dump-autoload` it? Sometime it works!

Answer (score 0):

put the Product class under a namespace.

```
<?php
namespace Foo; //change this to whatever you like

class Product extends \Eloquent
{

}
```

then use it like `new Foo\Product()`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But your solution doesn't work.

Comment: before doing save(), do a `echo get_class($product); die;` to see what class you instantiate

Comment: This is what I get `object(Product)[155]
  protected 'connection' => null`

Comment: and you're sure there isn't another Product class in your project.
try searching for 'class Product' in the project files

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. I just found it is caused by conflict with Migration. Why Migration? Isn't it only run when we run artisan migrate?